# Is it possible to generate keyboard inputs in my Xul app programmatically?

Tags: xul, keyboard-events

Is it possible to generate keyboard inputs in my Xul app programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tom,

Yes you can, target is a reference to a DOM element.

```
function triggerKeypressEvent(target) {

    var evt = document.createEvent('Events');
    evt.initEvent('keypress', true, true);

    evt.view     = window;
    evt.altKey   = false;
    evt.ctrlKey  = true;
    evt.shiftKey = false;
    evt.metaKey  = false;
    evt.keyCode  = 0;
    evt.charCode = 'x'; //Simulate user entering the "ctrl+X" keyboard shortcut

    target.dispatchEvent();

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can also use initKeyEvent. :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initKeyEvent

Comment: Thanks! But working with it, I realized that you missed the argument to target.dispatchEvent(). Also, after dispatched, looks like the charCode and keyCode are undefined, even if I had set it.. I'm making some more tests here.